# react.js this2.setState is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

hello everyone im trying to redirect user\ to home page when he signs out , however im running into some issues. Im using redirect in react router and im supposed to be redirect to home page , because redirect is true but instead im getting a wierd error saying this2.setState is not a function.

Anybody knows what this means? thanks for the help!

```
import React from "react";
import {
  Collapse,
  Navbar,
  NavbarToggler,
  NavbarBrand,
  Nav,
  Button,
  NavItem,
  NavLink,
  UncontrolledDropdown,
  DropdownToggle,
  DropdownMenu,
  DropdownItem
} from "reactstrap";
import { withRouter } from "react-router";
import Icon from "react-icons-kit";
import { car } from "react-icons-kit/fa/car";
import { Redirect, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import app from "../config/dev";
export default class NavigatioBar extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      authenticated: false,
      currentUser: null,
      redirect: false,
      isOpen: false
    };
    this.toggle = this.toggle.bind(this);
  }
  toggle() {
    this.setState({
      isOpen: !this.state.isOpen
    });
  }

  signout() {
    app
      .auth()
      .signOut()
      .then(user => {
        this.setState({ redirect: true });
      });
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    app.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
      if (user) {
        this.setState({
          currentUser: user,
          authenticated: true
        });
      } else {
        this.setState({
          currentUser: null,
          authenticated: false
        });
      }
    });
  }
  render() {
    const { redirect } = this.state;

    if (redirect) {
      return <Redirect to="/" />;
    }
    alert(this.state.authenticated);
    const authenticated = this.state.authenticated;
    return (
      <div>
        <Navbar color="primary" dark expand="md">
          <div className="container">
            <NavbarBrand href="/">
              <Icon className="car-icon" icon={car} />
              G66 CARS
            </NavbarBrand>
            <NavbarToggler onClick={this.toggle} />
            <Collapse isOpen={this.state.isOpen} navbar>
              <Nav className="ml-auto" navbar>
                <NavItem>
                  <NavLink href="/cars">CARS</NavLink>
                </NavItem>
                <NavItem>
                  <NavLink href="/">FINANCE</NavLink>
                </NavItem>
                <NavItem>
                  <NavLink href="/">SERVICE</NavLink>
                </NavItem>
                <NavItem>
                  <NavLink href="/">PARTS</NavLink>
                </NavItem>
                <UncontrolledDropdown nav>
                  <DropdownToggle nav caret>
                    ABOUT
                  </DropdownToggle>

                  <DropdownMenu>
                    {authenticated ? (
                      <DropdownItem onClick={this.signout}>
                        <Button classname="btn-btn-primary">SignOut </Button>
                      </DropdownItem>
                    ) : (
                      <DropdownItem>
                        <Link to="/login"> Login </Link>
                      </DropdownItem>
                    )}

                    <DropdownItem>ABOUT US</DropdownItem>
                    <DropdownItem>STAFF</DropdownItem>
                    <DropdownItem>CONTACT US</DropdownItem>
                  </DropdownMenu>
                </UncontrolledDropdown>
              </Nav>
            </Collapse>
          </div>
        </Navbar>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Probably means you're running it outside of the instance's context; if you search for React component method binding you will find this all over the place.

Comment: Which line gives the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
signout = () => {
   app.auth().signOut().then((user) => {
    this.setState ({ redirect: true })
    })
}
```

signout doesn't have this context.

Comment: any idea why navbar is dissapearing when i signout?

Answer (score 1):

Try binding the `signout()` function in the constructor to get `this` context:

```
this.signout = this.signout.bind(this);
```

Until arrow functions, every new function defined its own `this` value. As Anshul wrote, arrow functions do not have their own `this` context. So you can use `signout = () => {}` in your `NavigationBar` component and it will automatically have access to its `this` context.